# How do I set my default (spawn) property?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I own 2 properties in the PS4 version of GTA V (Del Perro and Eclipse Towers). Right now, Del Perro is my default one, how do I make the Eclipse Towers my default (spawn) property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Select Menu (Hold down the Touch Screen on PS4) and go down to "Spawn Location".